# kendo ui grid - how to cancelChanges while keeping the edit dialog open

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendoUI grid, and I am binding the error event with an error handler, in which I would like to prevent the popup dialog from closing and also cancel any changes such as row deletion or editing. It seems I can do one or the other, but not both. I have tried changing the order of the calls, etc. but still the first one that gets called works. Below is my handler with comments:

```
    function returnError(e) {        
        var grid = $("#mmdKendoGrid").data("kendoGrid");

        //prevent popup editor from closing
        grid.one("dataBinding", function (e) {            
            e.preventDefault();
        });

        //cancel any pending changes such as edited data, and restore any removed rows.
        grid.cancelChanges();
}
```

Comment: Where do you register `returnError`? If it is done properly you do not have to worry about `preventDefault` and such things. Maybe https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom-validation helps you out.

Comment: i'm using the mvc version, and just bind the error event to that event handler. The particular appraoch with preventDefault was suggested by telerik.

Comment: Fine, MVC it is: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing-custom-validation But even then you should not worry about these things. Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt.

Comment: Here is another technique: https://www.telerik.com/blogs/handling-server-side-validation-errors-in-your-kendo-ui-grid